# Is it practical to use transparent PNGs instead of JPGs for product shots?

Tags: image

I know this might get closed as too subjective, but let's give it a shot as it's probably relevant to a lot of Magento stores out there and given a certain set of constraints, there is probably a reasonably clear answer as to the best overall solution.

I'm wondering whether it's a good idea to use transparent PNGs for product shots instead of JPGs.  I've read (https://stackoverflow.com/a/7752936/1117286) that PNG-24 file size can be as much as 5X that of a similarly compressed JPG file, but I'm not sure if that figure is accurate or up-to-date with current compression tools out there.

Obviously for a merchant that can place products against a white background and doesn't plan on changing that any time soon, JPGs would make a lot more sense.

In our case, we have some product shots that are against a textured background and others that are against a white background.  The product shots that are against a textured background we just use one gigantic image for the whole thing.

So there would be a clear benefit to transparent PNGs in those cases.  And even for the other images that are currently against a white background, we may want to place them also against a textured background at some point in the future - so transparent PNGs would give us some nice future-proofing.

We're also responsive and we get a fair amount of mobile traffic, so we want to keep that in mind.

Given this set of constraints, is using transparent PNGs a reasonable solution?  I've yet to find any eCommerce sites out there using transparent PNGs, would be interesting if anyone could post links to them.

Comment: You could always progressively load PNGs. Ie. load a page with a lower resolution, proportionally stretched image, then programatically replace it when the larger image has been loaded in the background. That way you'll still have punchy load times and can preserve a quality image. But those with low-bandwidth connections will be penalised.

Comment: Ah right, good call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. If you have 10,000 products and show 50 per page — then no. If you show under 10 products — then yes.

Technical note: PNG-24 contains no alpha channel and is significantly smaller than PNG-32 (24-bit plus 8-bit alpha) but still much larger than a JPG with similar optical compression.

Paints will be slightly slower but decoding difference is negligible between formats.

You may want to look into serving WebP, but it's far from universal: https://www.andrewmunsell.com/blog/png-vs-webp

Comment: Right - it's probably the list pages that are going to suffer a lot more than the product detail page which is what I was primarily thinking about initially.

Comment: Ya WebP doesn't have enough support for us unfortunately: http://caniuse.com/webp

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, transparent PNGs are just not compressed enough to be a viable solution for product images. Especially if you are enabling image zoom, as you may have an image that is 1500px. Doing a comparison using Photoshop's "Save for Web", a PNG-24 is roughly 10x the size of a compressed JPG.

[image]

Comment: I just came across this tool that reduces the number of colors in a PNG: https://tinypng.com/ I was able to cut the sample PNG size in half. However you're still looking at 5x filesize. And integrating it with Magento would require connecting through their API: https://tinypng.com/developers

Comment: Thanks Erik!  So it looks like that 5X figure is pretty accurate then.

Comment: Great point about product zoom - that's something that's probably huge for 99% of merchants out there - we don't use it currently - the nature of our products aren't such that people are going to be too interested in zooming in as they would with clothes or many other types of products.